# How to pass variables from a controller to a view and vice versa in extjs4 MVC?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I need to pass some variables from a controller to its view or to another view. How can i do this in extjs4's MVC structure?

Comment: Have you tried using the namespace variable. Let say I have a xx as namespace and I want to pass yy to my view. You should be able to do xx.yy = "someValue" in your controller and use that in your view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using [Passive View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html), where the view has as little logic as possible.

Your controller can get access to any of the widgets in the view, via ComponentQuery. You can then write code in the controller to set or read values from the view.

You can also use the form.loadRecord() method to load a model into a view/form.

The widgets in the view communicate with the controller by raising events that are then handled by the controller.

You should load all of your controllers when the application starts.

Your controller should only have event handlers, and should never use the refs array or getView() functions (else you won't be able to control multiple instances of the same view).

Create and destroy your views at will. Pass in callback functions to communicate from parent to child view.

Answer (score 5):

If you are creating  a object of view from controller then pass that variable directly   e.g.  `Ext.create('view.myview',{id:Ext.id(),myVariable:"someValue"});`
and you can access it in view's initComponent method    as 
`initComponent: function() { this.myVariable }`

Comment: could you give complete example, i have same problem, and i don't know how to call `myVariable` in textfield @PankajAvhad